# Joomla Extension Komento Installation Not Creating Database Tables

Tags: joomla3.0

I am trying to install a Joomla 3.0 plugin called [Komento](http://stackideas.com/docs/komento.html). When I go to Extensions->Extension Manager->Upload Package File and select the extension from the upload package file tab (for Joomla 2.5-3.0) it gives the error

```
An error has occurred.
SQL=SHOW FIELDS FROM `komento_activities`
```

The table komento_activities does not exist in my database. It appears as if it is trying to create it, but cannot. I do not see any errors in my logs. The extension website does not offer any troubleshooting for this problem.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting suggestions?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted their customer support and send them a ticket on this? I have experience with them and they were very friendly and helpful.

It looks like Joomla is having permission issues creating the table on your site and you should definitely contact their customer support in their official page.